# Sublattice model for ternary system

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, phase-transition, software, phase-diagram

Much like in [an earlier post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760011/calculating-phase-diagram-of-rm-al-rm-cu-with-sublattice-models), I'm now calculating the phase diagram
of a ternary system (Ag-Al-Cu, to be specific), which has some phases modelled as sublattices (using [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2004.06.078) publication for the description).
With the help and method of the earlier post, I have already managed to model the theta phase, (Al)2(Ag,Al,Cu), for the liquidus surface, but am struggling with the other ones, being for:

- epsilon, (Ag,Al,Cu)(Ag,Cu)
- eta, (Ag,Cu)(Al,Cu)
- gammaH and gammaD83, (Al)4(Al,Cu)(Ag,Cu)8
- zeta2, (Al)9(Ag,Cu)11

As tipped to in the earlier mentioned post, I've used the CALPHAD book of Saunders (chapter 5.4, and specifically section 5.4.2 and its equation (5.37)) to try to understand the use of the sublattice model, but I must admit I find it all very difficult to understand.

Specifically the use of "sites", "vacancies", "compound array" $I$, and the "product of site fractions from the $Y$ matrix" $P_I (Y)$, and how to go from the knowledge about the lattice description (e.g. (Ag,Al,Cu)(Ag,Cu)) to such a mathematical description.

Let's use the epsilon phase as an example.

From what I understand, as there is just one of each sublattice ((Ag,Al,Cu) and (Ag,Cu)), that should give the site fractions $y_\mathrm{Ag}^1=y_\mathrm{Al}^1=y_\mathrm{Cu}^1=1$ and $y_\mathrm{Ag}^2=y_\mathrm{Cu}^2=1$.
Now how does that translate to a the "product of site fractions", so that I can calculate the reference term $\sum_{I0} P_{I0}(Y) \cdot {}^0G_{I0}$?
In the reference for Ag-Al-Cu, I have the following [from its table 3]:
$$
\epsilon\text{-phase: } (\mathrm{Ag,Al,Cu})(\mathrm{Ag,Cu})\\
{}^0 G^\epsilon_\mathrm{Al:Ag} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Al} = 160000 + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Al}\\
{}^0 G^\epsilon_\mathrm{Ag:Cu} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Cu} = 85000 + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Cu}\\
{}^0 G^\epsilon_\mathrm{Cu:Ag} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} - H^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Cu} = 85000 + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Ag} + GH^\mathrm{SER}_\mathrm{Cu}
$$

together with the following from [COST507](https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/35a95440-10ac-45f3-bd90-0fe0a0006aaf), which it is based on [from its "System Al-Cu" chapter]:
$$
\text{Phase AlCu-}\epsilon \quad [(\mathrm{Al,Cu})(\mathrm{Cu})]\\
G^\circ(T) - H^{\circ,\mathrm{fcc-}A1}_\mathrm{Al} (298.15\mathrm{ K}) - H^{\circ,\mathrm{fcc-}A1}_\mathrm{Cu} (298.15\mathrm{ K}) = \mathrm{G(Al:Cu)} =
-36976 + 1.2 T + \mathrm{GHSER}_\mathrm{Al} + \mathrm{GHSER}_\mathrm{Cu}\\
\\
G^\circ(T) - 2.0 H^{\circ,\mathrm{fcc-}A1}_\mathrm{Cu} (298.15\mathrm{ K}) = \mathrm{G(Cu:Cu)} = 2.0 \mathrm{GBCC}_\mathrm{Cu}\\
L^{0,\mathrm{AlCu-}\epsilon}_\mathrm{Al,Cu:Cu} = 7600 - 24 T\\
L^{1,\mathrm{AlCu-}\epsilon}_\mathrm{Al,Cu:Cu} = -72000
$$

The ideal term should be $R T \sum_s N^s \sum_i y_i^s \ln y_i^s$, $N^s$ being the "total number of sites on the sublattice", which I assume would then be for the epsilon phase: $N^1 = 3$ and $N^2 = 2$. But with my integer definitions of $y_i^s$, the logarithm is senseless, and I must obviously have been doing something wrong (did I mix it with the "number of sites on each sublattice" $a_s$?).
In the earlier post, the site fraction was explained as being a linear relation so that the possible atomic fractions $x_i$ map from 0 to 1, which for (Ag,Al,Cu)(Ag,Cu) as I understand would be for

- Ag: 0 to 1 atomic fraction, so $y_\mathrm{Ag} = x_\mathrm{Ag}$
- Al: 0 to 0.5 atomic fraction, so $y_\mathrm{Al} = 2 x_\mathrm{Al}$
- Cu: 0 to 1 atomic fraction, so $y_\mathrm{Cu} = x_\mathrm{Cu}$

But it is not clear to me how that would fit in with the description of the different sublattices.

The excess term is given as $\sum_{Z > 0} \sum_{I Z} P_{I Z}(Y) \cdot L_{I Z}$. As the Ag-Al-Cu publication has no $L$ terms, I'm not sure whether that means that there is no excess term, or whether to use ones from COST507 only.

I've also looked at the [original paper for the sublattice model](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-3697(81)90144-X), but did not understand more.
As can be understood from this post, I'm mighty confused, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use images for text and equations. Use MathJax instead.

Comment: Despite that, if you do not get an answer here, you can consider to ask this question on Matter Modeling SE. Please note our guidelines about cross-posting.

Answer (score 0):

Especially with the help of [this document I found online](https://coursecontent.indusuni.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2020/05/CMS-Unit-4.2.pdf), I have managed to model every phase I mentioned, *except* for the epsilon phase. (i.e., I've managed to successfully model the eta, gammaH, gammaD83 and zeta2 phases)
As this only explains how to calculate the Gibbs energy for some of the phases, I'll not mark it as an accepted answer, but it will hopefully still be of help to whoever may stumble over this.

Using the gammaH as an illustration, the (Al)4:(Al,Cu):(Ag,Cu)8 phase is modelled in this way:

- The site fractions are calculated as explained in [the initial post for the Al-Cu binary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760011/calculating-phase-diagram-of-rm-al-rm-cu-with-sublattice-models), where the $y$ value is mapped from 0 to 1 for the possible $x$ concentration. This is done for each site ((Al), (Al,Cu), and (Ag,Cu), which are labeled $y_i^1$, $y_i^2$, and $y_i^3$ for component $i$. Note the integers are indicating the site, and are not exponentials). As there is only (Al) on the first site, there is always only Al there, and therefore $y_\mathrm{Al}^1 = 1$. As there is no other component on the site, there is no site fraction for it (i.e. $y_\mathrm{Ag}^1$ and $y_\mathrm{Cu}^1$ is not defined). For the two other sites, Ag, Al and Cu can be varied. In a ternary system, there are two free concentrations, where I'll use $x_\mathrm{Ag}$ and $x_\mathrm{Al}$. Then, the site fractions for those are $y_\mathrm{Al}^2 = 13 x_\mathrm{Al} - 4$ on the second site (as the total Al concentration goes from a minimum of $\frac{4 + 0 + 0}{4 + 1 + 8} = \frac{4}{13}$ to a maximum of $\frac{4 + 1 + 0}{4 + 1 + 8} = \frac{5}{13}$), and $y_\mathrm{Ag}^3 = \frac{13}{8} x_\mathrm{Al}$ on the third site (as the total Ag concentration goes from a minimum of $\frac{0 + 0 + 0}{4 + 1 + 8} = 0$ to a maximum of $\frac{0 + 0 + 8}{4 + 1 + 8} = \frac{8}{13}$). The site fractions for the third component (copper) are then, following the definition $\sum_i y_i^s = 1$, calculated to be $y_\mathrm{Cu}^2 = 1 - y_\mathrm{Al}^2$ and $y_\mathrm{Cu}^3 = 1 - y_\mathrm{Ag}^3$.
- The product of site fractions $P$ is simply the product of the possible combinations, so that the pure term for the gammaH phase consists of the possible products $y_\mathrm{Al}^1 y_\mathrm{Al}^2 y_\mathrm{Ag}^3$, $y_\mathrm{Al}^1 y_\mathrm{Al}^2 y_\mathrm{Cu}^3$, $y_\mathrm{Al}^1 y_\mathrm{Cu}^2 y_\mathrm{Ag}^3$, and $y_\mathrm{Al}^1 y_\mathrm{Cu}^2 y_\mathrm{Cu}^3$. These are then multiplied with their respective thermodynamic parameters ${}^0 G^{\gamma\mathrm{H}}$. See the source code at the bottom for the full equation.
- The ideal term is simply the "standard" $R T y^s_i \ln y^s_i$ term for each single site fraction, multiplied with the "total number of sites on the sublattice $N^s$", which is 4 for the first site, 1 for the second, and 8 for the third.
- The excess term is shaped as described for the given parameters $L$, where the description in the subscript explains which site fractions are multiplied together. For the parameter ${}^0 L^{\gamma\mathrm{H}}_\mathrm{Al:Al,Cu:Ag}$, the excess part term is then $y^1_\mathrm{Al} y^2_\mathrm{Al} y^2_\mathrm{Cu} y^3_\mathrm{Ag} {}^0 L^{\gamma\mathrm{H}}_\mathrm{Al:Al,Cu:Ag}$. Again, see the source code for the full equation.
- In the end, the entire equation is divided by the sum of number of sites, so $4 + 1 + 8 = 13$. The reason why is still unclear to me. If it was to scale down the site fractions $y^s_i$ to always be within 0 and 1, it would have to be divided as many times as sites, but this is not the case (it's divided only once, and not three times). Also, the ideal contribution is non-linearly dependent on a site fraction, so it also can not be explained. But it works (by comparing the calculated liquidus surface with that presented in the publication from where the parameters are from), so that's at least something.

And here is the Python source code I used to calculate the Gibbs energy for the phase:

```
# Phase gammaH, (Al)4:(Al,Cu):(Ag,Cu)8
def AgAlCuGibbsGammaH (xAg, xAl, T):
    # Thermodynamic parameters from litterature:
    # Ternary (Witusiewicz2005, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2004.06.078 )
    G0AlAlAg = -10000 + 5 * AlG0Fcc(T) + 8 * AgG0Fcc(T) # pure elements (AlG0Fcc, AgG0Fcc, etc) from Dinsdale1991, https://doi.org/10.1016/0364-5916(91)90030-N
    G0AlCuAg = 18300 + 4430 * T - 766 * T * np.log(T) + 0.80 * T**2 + 4 * AlG0Fcc(T) + CuG0Fcc(T) + 8 * AgG0Fcc(T)
    L0AlAlCuAg = 23000 + 6110 * T - 1061 * T * np.log(T) + 1.115 * T**2
    L0AlCuAgCu = 23000 + 6110 * T - 1061 * T * np.log(T) + 1.115 * T**2
    # Binary (COST507, https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/35a95440-10ac-45f3-bd90-0fe0a0006aaf )
    G0AlAlCu = -219258.0 - 45.5 * T + 5 * AlG0Fcc(T) + 8 * CuG0Fcc(T)
    G0AlCuCu = -200460.0 - 58.5 * T + 4 * AlG0Fcc(T) + 9 * CuG0Fcc(T)

    # Number on the sites
    N1 = 4
    N2 = 1
    N3 = 8
    
    # Site fractions
    yAl1 = 1

    yAl2 = 13 * xAl - 4
    yCu2 = 1 - yAl2

    yAg3 = 13 / 8 * xAg
    yCu3 = 1 - yAg3

    # Pure, ideal and excess contributions to the Gibbs energy
    pure = yAl1 * yAl2 * yAg3 * G0AlAlAg + yAl1 * yCu2 * yAg3 * G0AlCuAg + yAl1 * yAl2 * yCu3 * G0AlAlCu + yAl1 * yCu2 * yCu3 * G0AlCuCu

    # Note how N1 * yAl1 * np.log(yAl1) is zero everywhere, as yAl1 = 1, and np.log(1) = 0, so we don't calculate it here.
    ideal = R * T * (N2 * (yAl2 * np.log(yAl2) + yCu2 * np.log(yCu2)) +
                     N3 * (yAg3 * np.log(yAg3) + yCu3 * np.log(yCu3)))

    excess = yAl1 * yAl2 * yCu2 * yAg3 * L0AlAlCuAg + yAl1 * yCu2 * yAg3 * yCu3 * L0AlCuAgCu
    
    # Divide by total number of sites
    dividend = N1 + N2 + N3

    pure /= dividend
    ideal /= dividend
    excess /= dividend
    
    # Gibbs energy is equal to the sum of the different parts
    return pure + ideal + excess
```